# How to do basic authentification in codenameone ConnectionRequest

Tags: http, authentication, codenameone

This question has been asked but my problem remains.

```
    final String info = "{\"tweet\":\"example\"}";

    String url = "https://api.orchestrate.io/v0" + "/" + "roars/seinecle/events/?pretty=true";
    ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest() {
        @Override
        protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
            os.write(info.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }

    };

    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setPost(true);
    request.setHttpMethod("PUT");
    request.setContentType("application/json");
    request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic MzUzOThlOTQtZjUzMy00ZGZkLTgx==");
```

I get a 401 error. What the helper console says I should write as a request:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works for us:

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeNoNewline((user + ":" + pass).getBytes());
auth.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

It looks like you are doing Twitter connectivity, check out our old `TwitterRESTService` class and its source in the git repository. Its a bit outdated though.

Also check out how we write UTF-8 which might fix this issue:

```
if(shouldWriteUTFAsGetBytes()) {
    os.write(val.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
} else {
    OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
    w.write(val.toString());
}
```

There are minor differences between Java implementations that might only work for one and not the other.

You might also need a newline in the message body before or after.

I suggest using our network monitor in the simulator tool and reviewing the outgoing request.

Comment: Thought I got it solved but pb remains... I don't do Twitter actually, that was just a placeholder name.

Comment: I added some other ideas. I think the 401 might be a misleading error message here.